# Laminating two column arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Assume I have two numpy (N, 1) column arrays.  I know their length to be equal:

```
>>> a
array([[0.],
       [2.],
       [4.],
       [6.]])
>>> b
array([[0.],
       [1.],
       [2.],
       [3.]])
```

and I'd like to "laminate" them side by side to form an (N, 2) array.  The following works:

```
>>> np.array((a, b)).reshape(2, len(a)).transpose()
array([[0., 0.],
       [2., 1.],
       [4., 2.],
       [6., 3.]])
```

... but is there a simpler, more direct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just stack them horizontally using `np.hstack` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html))

```
>>> np.hstack((a, b))
array([[0., 0.],
       [2., 1.],
       [4., 2.],
       [6., 3.]]
```

Comment: Loving np and loving stackoverflow.  Thanks!